# Webkit Porting Guide

Tags: javascript, c++, webkit

Is there a comprehensive document on how to port Webkit to a new platform? I am especially interested in the JavaScript side of things.

Answer (score 1):

On the official web site of webkit, there is a How To Port section on the wiki that is quiet well defined.

( http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/SuccessfulPortHowTo )
( http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WikiStart )

Comment: Thanks but not hugely useful. I am more interested in what needs to change to get things working.